# What is the font of the new Microsoft Logo? Or Microsoft Office?

Tags: fonts

Title kind of says it. I'm a fan of it and curious if anyone knew what it is.

Comment: Found this shortly after.  Stupid Google.  Always knowing what I want... :)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700394.aspx

Comment: Wow.  Even more information about Segoe.  

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segoe

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to this link http://fontsinuse.com/uses/2007/the-new-microsoft-logo it is Segoe

Answer (score 3):

Segoe. The font "Segoe UI" is slightly different and included in Windows/Office, however I can't find the original Segoe font anywhere

Comment: Yeah I was noticing the Segoe UI one was a little different.  I think I'm just struggling with how to tweak the properties to emulate this.